# How can I count double values in SQL Server, comparing multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, count, distinct

I am setting up a Data Quality Management report for an organisation with multiple administrations. From all the administrations is the data stored in one DataWarehouse. The problem is that different administrations use the same code, but different description for certain fields. One administration (A11) is leading. I want to count how many codes are double and how many rows they contain.

```
[administration]   [code_description]
 A11               1 / contract
 A11               3 / Supplier
 A23               1 / Contracts
 A23               3 / Supplier
 A31               1 / contract
 A31               3 / Delivery
 A56               1 / Contracts
 A56               3 / Delivery
```

There are 2 codes, but 4 different descriptions. code 1: contract/Contracts and code 3: Supplier/Delivery. The column code_description is one column that includes the code and the description.

I would like to find out how many records do have the same code as the A11 administration, but have a different description.

```
SELECT DISTINCT administration,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(code_description,'/','.'),2) as code, 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(code_description,'/','.'),1) as description
FROM db_table
WHERE administration IN
(
   SELECT administration
   FROM db_table
)
```

I don't know how to go from here, I have listed every option but I don't know how to iterate over the rows to check: if the codes are the same, but the description is different from the A11 administration.

I would like to have the amount of double values as an output.

```
'Amount double values: '   count_of_doubles
```

Comment: can you add your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Hello the following sqlcode will get every administration, and it's number of occurrence

```
  declare @X as table( administration nvarchar(200), code_description nvarchar(200) )  insert into @x select 'A11','1 / contract '  insert into @x select 'A23','1 / Contracts' insert into @x select 'A23', '3 / Supplier ' insert into @x select 'A31' ,'1 / contract ' insert into @x select 'A31' ,'1 / contract ' insert into @x select 'A31','3 / Delivery ' insert into @x select 'A56','1 / Contracts' insert into @x select 'A56','3 / Delivery '  insert into @x select 'A56','3 / Delivery '  insert into @x select 'A56','3 / Delivery '

    SELECT administration,count(*) CountOfAdiminitrators
    FROM @X
    GROUP BY administration
```

and the output as follows,the A11 is inserted once, A23 Twice and as follows:

[image: output of the query]